# MVC 5 inline response.write based on value not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, inline

Have text I need to change along with setting the color of the text based on values from the model being passed.
The value is blank when I'm trying to do it as below.

```
<p class="lbutton radius">
    SQL Cluster Online
    <span class="lbutton-addition">
        @if (Model.SQLClusterOnline) { Response.Write("Online"); } else { Response.Write("Offline"); }
    </span>
</p>
```

I also need to change the text color based on the value.

Comment: Why would you use `Response.Write` in MVC? I haven't done that since classic ASP.

Comment: Sorry still learning

Comment: razor view already writes html as response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Razor views, within the `@(...)` construct, you don't have to `Response.Write`. Just "return" the value.

```
<p class="lbutton radius">
    SQL Cluster Online
    <span class="lbutton-addition">
        @(Model.SQLClusterOnline ? "Online" : "Offline")
    </span>
</p>
```

**EDIT**

Here is what you want in the comment:

```
<span class="lbutton-addition @(Model.SQLClusterOnline ? "online" : "offline")" ></span>
```

Now create the classes `online` and `offline` and assign the `color` CSS property to whatever you want.

Comment: does this word the same in the class to control if I want the text color red or green?

Comment: Yes. Razor does'nt actually know where are you using the "output". It just "outputs" to whatever :)

Comment: span class="lbutton-addition" @(Model.SQLClusterOnline ? "style=\"color: green\"" : "style=\"color: red\"")> This doesn't seem to change the color.